# How do I give an image a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, hyperlink, addition

One of my resources in my Rails app has a URL attribute (string). The resource also has an image attribute, so I want to attach the url onto that image. How do I do that?

```
<div class="box">
<%= link_to (image_tag retailer.image(:medium)), retailer %>

<p class="description">
    <%= retailer.description %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_retailer_path(retailer) %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', retailer, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>
```

I want to add the link (string) in retailer.url to the image for when I click on it!

I tried replacing the last 'retailer' argument on the 2nd line of code with 'retailer.url', but it didn't work. With this code clicking on it just takes me to that resource's show page.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: What error message are you seeing?

Comment: could you please provide your whole form code? Do you getting any instance for `retailer` from controller?

Comment: So the retailer in this specific retailer instance in J. Crew. The string under its url attribute is 'www.jcrew.com'. When I put retailer.url as the second argument to link_to, I get this "No route matches [GET] "/www.jcrew.com"". How can I stop it from trying to find a path for it and just using the text in the string as a regular web address?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%= link_to " #{image_tag(image_tag retailer.image(:medium))}", "link_path" %>
```

Comment: This didn't work, the picture won't show now. For reference, this box div is supposed to represent a pin looking object on the web app. The pin is of a retailer, which includes its logo, a description, and a edit/destroy link. When I click on the logo, which is the picture, I would like it to use one of its attributes, called 'url', which contains a string of the link to the retailers website. I replaced link in your example with url, but I haven't set a route to the link attribute because there is no show page for it. When I click on it, I got "No route matches [GET] "/url_path". Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the image source needs to be inside the parathesis like this.

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/assets/104_white.png"), users_path(@user)%>
```

So in your case it would be:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(retailer.image(:medium)), retailer %>
```